# Page of posts made to look like homepage

Tags: posts, themes, pages

Is there any way i can get a page of posts from a certain category to look like the homepage (twentyeleven theme) of just blog posts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WordPress creates archive pages for categories. Using the Twenty Eleven demo, see this URL: http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/category/uncategorized/

Answer (score 0):

Its actually really simple to do. In the **'Appearance'** tab of the left had admin sidebar click **'Menu'** 
Once in menu you'll see a block called **'Categories'** click the check box of the catagory you want to appear on a page, then click **'Add to Menu'**

Go to your home page and you'll see that you have a new menu item that links to a page of post from that particular category.

Hope that helps.